# If 0 clear contents for multiple columns

Tags: excel, vba

I'm wondering how to make the following code work for multiple columns (D:P)?   I've already tried adding & ":"P" & "65536" to the range, without success.

```
For i = 5 To Range("D" & "65536").End(xlUp).Row Step 1
If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("D" & i), "0") = 1 Then
Range("D" & i).ClearContents
End If
Next i
```

Comment: Where exactly would this "0" be that you're looking for. I feel there's an easier way to do this, but right now you haven't provided much information. Also, is your "0" formatted as a string? Because that's what your implying by placing it between quotation marks.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use a nested loop and just call them by number? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/refer-to-cells-by-using-index-numbers

Comment: Why do you use Countif for testing if a cell contains a "0" And do you want to clear contents only in case every cell contains a 0 or do you want to clear in case just one has a 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Range("D5:P65536").Replace What:=0,Replacement:=""` to Replace all at once.

Comment: brilliant in it's simplicity. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the actual *column* and use the `Find()` method to perform your search. If your value exists in that range (range = column), then you can clear the contents that way.

```
Sub test()

    ' Just for illustration on the columns
    Const D& = 4:   Const P& = 16

    Dim ws As Worksheet, col As Long
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

    For col = D To P
        If Not ws.Columns(col).find(What:="0", LookAt:=xlWhole) Is Nothing Then
            ws.Columns(col).ClearContents
        End If
    Next col

End Sub
```